# MaterialDrawer crash on build

Tags: android, android-studio, materialdrawer

So I tried to build a MaterialDrawer sidebar for my Android app. But when the drawer hits build my app crashes..any ideas why?
My crash log looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: please pass an activity
at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder.build(DrawerBuilder.java:1300)
```

I don't understand where that activity should be passed and it is not. I mention that I build my MaterialDrawer sidebar in a class that I will use as a parent of multiple activities. So the purpose of this class is solely for generating this side menu for my app.
My code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sidebar_menu);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        User u = MainProvider.sharedInstance().getCurrentUser(this);
        TextView usernameText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        String profilePictureUrl = u.getSettings().get("profile_picture").getAsString();
        //initialize and create the image loader logic
        DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
            @Override
            public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
                Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
                Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
            }
        });
        //if you want to update the items at a later time it is recommended to keep it in a variable
        PrimaryDrawerItem item1 = new PrimaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(1).withName(R.string.dashboard);
        SecondaryDrawerItem item2 = new SecondaryDrawerItem().withIdentifier(2).withName(R.string.point_of_sale);
        // Create the AccountHeader
        AccountHeader headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.side_nav_bar)
                .addProfiles(
                        new ProfileDrawerItem().withName(u.getUsername()).withEmail(u.getEmail()).withIcon(Uri.parse(profilePictureUrl))
                )
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean currentProfile) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
        new DrawerBuilder()
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        item1,
                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        item2,
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.point_of_sale)
                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        // do something with the clicked item :D
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();
    }
```

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an Activity in your fluent builder.

aka - You forgot to specify `.withActivity(this)`.

Try this:

```
    new DrawerBuilder()
        .withActivity(this)
        .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
        .withToolbar(toolbar)
        .addDrawerItems(
            item1,
            new DividerDrawerItem(),
            item2,
            new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.point_of_sale)
        )
        .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem)
            {
                // do something with the clicked item :D
                return false;
            }
        })
        .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
        .build();
```